# Can't read a file that contains a question mark in name

Tags: ruby, file

I have a file with a name something like: `/path/to/file/dir with spaces/mytiff-?.tif`. In irb I try both the following:

```
open("/path/to/file/dir with spaces/mytiff-?.tif", 'rb')
File.open("/path/to/file/dir with spaces/mytiff-?.tif", 'rb')
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory.
```

I've also tried replacing the `?` with `\?` in the string.

I'm using ruby 2.0.0. File is network drive (CIFS), client is a mac (lion).

**Update**

Thanks for the help. The problem is still not solved.

```
$ ls "/Volumes/rmrpp/MLP Library/Bridgland 1927 - North Saskatchewan/Stations/420/Repeat Masters/"                    
HIG2008_B27_420-100.tif HIG2008_B27_420-90.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-92.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-94.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-96.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-98.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-?.tif
HIG2008_B27_420-101.tif HIG2008_B27_420-91.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-93.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-95.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-97.tif  HIG2008_B27_420-99.tif
$ irb
1.9.3p194 :001 > t = File.open("/Volumes/rmrpp/MLP Library/Bridgland 1927 - North Saskatchewan/Stations/420/Repeat Masters/HIG2008_B27_420-?.tif",'rb'); nil
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /Volumes/rmrpp/MLP Library/Bridgland 1927 - North Saskatchewan/Stations/420/Repeat Masters/HIG2008_B27_420-?.tif
    from (irb):1:in `initialize'
    from (irb):1:in `open'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/mlp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
1.9.3p194 :002 > t = File.open("/Volumes/rmrpp/MLP Library/Bridgland 1927 - North Saskatchewan/Stations/420/Repeat Masters/HIG2008_B27_420-98.tif",'rb'); nil
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :003 > t.size
 => 50124180
```

As you can see, the file exists (I'm listing it in bash). I go into irb and try to read the file as a binary. The file path is quoted. It fails. I try another file from the same directory and it works.

I think @mu_is_too_short is correct. Maybe the ? isn't a question mark at all. The only viable solution I can think of is to manually rename the files with the mystery question mark. Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't try to read .tif files using `r` mode. That is going to read a binary file as text. Instead use `rb` mode to read it as binary.

Comment: Are you sure that's a `?` and not some other character that you terminal (or whatever) doesn't know how to display?

Comment: I created a file with a `-?` and can can write and read to it with no problem.

Comment: I think his issue is mostly with the space in the directory name.  The question mark is not the problem, he solved it with the escape.

Comment: `ls` changes unknown characters to `?`, so it won't help reveal what the `?` really is. Rather than `ls /some/path`, try `ruby -e 'Dir.foreach("/some/path") { |item| p item }'`, which should show you what it *really* is.

Comment: I tried that and it still came out as a question mark. I also change the name of the file through Finder (Mac) and I get an operation not permitted. Permissions are okay though.

Comment: You can use ls and pipe the listing of that directory to a file.  The `ls -N` and `ls --show-control-chars` may help get the real character if it is indeed not a question mark.  Otherwise, why not load the file listing using Ruby dynamically?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the file exists, there is no problem opening a file like this:

```
folder_file = './temp directory/file-?.txt'
File.open(folder_file, 'r').close
```

This works fine.

See Tin Man's suggestion about how to actually open the `.tif` file.

As you can see, I created the following file myster-file_char?.txt

```
 $: ls
get_listing.rb  myster-file_char?.txt
```

You can get this stored in a variable, though I only use `Dir.glob` here to view it.

```
puts Dir.glob("**.*").inspect
```

Everything is now revealed in what character it is.  Though I should be able to use it directly as is to open and edit the file in Ruby.  Though like The Tin Man stated, you are asking about a binary file.

```
 $: ruby get_listing.rb 
["myster-file_char\u0016.txt", "get_listing.rb"]
```

The character that is actually there is a <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.  Hope this finally helps to unravel the mystery.

Comment: Why do double quotes not work, and how do single quotes resolve the issue?

Comment: @icktoofay you are right to ask, there is nothing in this answer to solve the problem.  I can't get it to fail as long as the file exists.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response vgoff. So I think it actually was a question mark. It seems the core of the problem had to do with CIFS. When I mounted the share on my mac, I couldn't change the filename, let alone read it using ruby. When I ssh'd onto the server, I was able to change the filename (removing the ? and replacing with a 'q') fixing the problem.